# Translate a JS string from interface translations doesn't work

Tags: 8, javascript, i18n-l10n

I've a problem about string translations.

I've built a multi-language site and in a custom module, in a JS file, I've used the function `t()` to make translatable some strings. These strings appear in `/admin/config/regional/translate` and I'm able to edit their value, but then, after cleared cache when I visit the site I see the strings not translated.

The strangest things is that for other elements the system works. I'm not able to debug this, my apache error and access logs are clear, nothing also in the message log of Drupal.

Anyone can help me? 
Thank u in advance

Comment: Hey hey, please show us some of your JS code. And your `*.libraries.yml`. And please verify as suggested below, if using `Drupal.t()` fixed it for you.

Answer (score 3):

Which string you want to translate before that you can use  **Drupal.t**

like

```
var optionsList = '<option value="" selected>' + Drupal.t('Navigate...') + '</option>';
```

Comment: Not to forget to add the correct dependencies in `*.libraries.yml`.

Comment: Also don’t forget the context argument.

Comment: Complete sample from `menu_ui.js`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49939159/2199525.